# How can I store an enum value which matches any data for a single variant?

Tags: rust, enums

I'm trying to build a publisher-subscriber mechanism using Enums to represent the different events which can occur. Each event can have some data associated with it, e.g. a key press could be an event with the key code being the data.

What I'd like to do is allow a subscriber to subscribe to all instances of an enum variant. So continuing the key press example, a subscriber could ask to be notified of all key presses and then receive the enum variant with the key code data inside.

**How can I store a value which represents a match of the data within an enum?**

It'd be nice to use syntax similar to a `match` statement:

```rust
enum Event {
    KeyPress(char),
}

trait Subscriber {
    fn callback(&self, event: &Event);
}

struct DummySubscriber {}

impl Subscriber for DummySubscriber {
    fn callback(&self, event: &Event) {
        /* do some stuff */
    }
}

fn main() {
    let subscriber = DummySubscriber {};
    let subscriptions = HashMap::new();

    subscriptions.insert(Event::KeyPress(_), subscriber);
    subscriptions.insert(Event::KeyPress('a'), subscriber);
}
```

I have got something working using `std::mem::discriminant` but this is limited to matching all instances of a variant, i.e. it doesn't allow for pattern matching.

Comment: FWIW a common pattern in Rust web frameworks is the *typemap*, where the map is literally keyed by a type. One likely advantage is it would let you statically type the handlers as e.g. the key `<KeyPress as Key>::Value` could be a `Vec<fn(char)>` or somesuch, rather than a callback taking a generic `Event`. Obviously this would have the drawback that registering against multiple events would require multiple callbacks / handlers, but that could also be an advantage as usually I'd expect the handlers to have little overlap.

Comment: Thanks @Masklinn, I'm just having a go with that crate to see if it applies.